# Asp Net Mvc Routing without action on multiple Controllers

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes, controller

My Asp Net MVC Application contains 4 Controllers:
Home | Training | Diet | Configuration

```
 routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Authorize", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

When I want to do a `RedirectToAction("Configurator","Configuration") it tells me the Route isnt found. [Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tmX2m.png)
I tried adding different types of Routes but I never achieved the following scenario: 
I just want the URL to doesnt contain the Controllername:
So instead of:
Before: https://localhost/Home/Login 
After:  https://localhost/Login
but also 
Before: https://localhost/Diet/DailyData
After:  https://localhost/DailyData

I have a lot of Methods in every Controller so I don't wanna set up for a Route for every Method.
Is this possible and how?

Thank you already so much in advance!

Comment: What version mvc are you using?

Comment: @Sergey I using MVC Version 5.2.7.0 :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add to RouteConfig after IgnoreRoutes

```
routes.IgnoreRoute(“{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}”);
 
routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
```

after this  you can use route attributes and add to the top of each controller

```
    [Route("[action]")]
    public class HomeController : ControllerBase

     [Route("[action]")]
    public class TrainingController : ControllerBase

....
```

you will need to add only 4 attributes -  one for each controller.

And return default route to it's default

```
  routes.MapRoute(
        name: “Default”,
        url: “{controller}/{action}/{id}”,
        defaults: new { controller = “Home”, action = “Index”, id = UrlParameter.Optional
```

it is always a good idea not to touch it. Make your default route like this

```
[Route("[action]")]
    public class HomeController : ControllerBase
{
[Route("~/Authorize")]
[Route("~/Home/Index")]
public IActionResult Authorize()
```

Comment: On little issue is still there: 
When I start my application it navigates to https://localhost:12345 and gives me 404 page but when I try https://localhost:12345/Home/Index or https://localhost:12345/Authorize it works perfectly! 
I changed my MapRoute back to Default like in your example tho :/ 

Except from that everything works like a charm! Thank you so damn much you already saved my day!

Comment: Adding [Route("")] to the top of the Authorize Methode fixed my problem so thank a lot for your help everythings just works fine now :)